# How to check if a string has any letters or characters?

Tags: javascript, string, input

I need to check if input has only numbers and spaces(no letters or characters).

Tried using .includes

```
var string = 'abc'

if(string.includes(A-Za)){
console.log('bad')
} else {
console.log('good')
}
```

Comment: do you like to check if it contains some characters or if it does not contain some characters?

Comment: [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: @NinaScholz i would like to check if it cointains any letters or characters(as if: commas,dots, clauses)

Comment: please edit your question and add some more use cases.

Comment: So do you only want to accept numbers and spaces. or reject any string that contains atleast one character? If its the later, do you want to reject all characters or just the english dictionary? Should `,./;` or `Γк` pass the check?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Regex.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
var string = 'abc'

if (/[A-Za-z]/.test(string)) {
  console.log('bad')
} else {
  console.log('good')
}
```

Comment: *I need to check if input has only numbers and spaces* . Your regex is not correct. That allow for example : `; ? / + =`

Comment: This won't always work if `string = "?"` you will get "good", but it actually isn't

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple regex that matches numbers from start to end:

```js
const bad = 'abc';
const good = 123;
const re = /^\d*$/;

const goodOrBad = str => re.test(str) ? "Good" : "Bad";

console.log(goodOrBad(bad));
console.log(goodOrBad(good));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(check("abc"));
console.log(check("123"));
console.log(check("123 123"));
console.log(check("123 abc"));

function check(txt) {
  return /^(\d|\s)*$/.test(txt) ? "good" : "bad";
}
```

Breakdown of: `^(\d|\s)*$`

- `^`: Start of string
- `$`: End of string
- `\d`: Match a number (Can also be written as `[0-9]`)
- `\s`: Match a space or any other whitespace character (if you just want space then )
- `\d|\s`: Match number or space
- `(\d|\s)*`: Match number or space 0-Many times (Can also be written as `(\d|\s){0,}`)

Comment: This to me looks like the correct solution, checking for both numbers and spaces, where the other answers do not

Comment: @NickParsons Not so sure anymore because OP said `i would like to check if it cointains any letters or characters(as if: commas,dots, clauses)`.

Comment: U either check if it has only numbers and spaces or if it has any numbers or characters. Its just reversed.

Comment: @TheMisterS Should a string that contains neither (i.e. `,./,`) print `good` or `bad`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with this regex **^[0-9]*$**

```js
console.log( /^[0-9]*$/.test('45') ? "Good" : "Bad")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

checking every character:

```
for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) { 
  if (isNan(string[i]) && string[i] == ' ') {
  console.log('bad')
} else {
  console.log('good')
}
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure if it checks a blank space(' ') it's gonna print good

Comment: Oh yes, I forget the blank space! You can add an and (&&) in the if